# Why JNDI it´s not recognize the bean from dataSource

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, datasource, jndi

Hi I want to separate the DataSource from the Server.xml from Liberty and explicitly include in the class the connection parameters as shown in the following link but, when I add the @Resource annotation gives me the following problem:
My Connector it´s mysql

No bean named 'jndi / mysql' available: not found in JNDI environment

Any contribution or help based on the theme will be well received. regards

I have tried to do a method where I return the data source of the bean with the proper notation @Bean and @Primary but the log is still the same

```
 @DataSourceDefinition(
                name= "java:comp/env/jdbc/mysql", 
                className = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mini_blog_es2?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", 
                user = "root",
                password = "tuna"
                ) })

`public class JPAConfigDatabase  { 
@Resource(lookup = "jndi/mysql")
    private DataSource dataSource; 
`

    // Get Method

    @Primary
        @Bean(name = "dataSource")
        public DataSource getDataSource()  {
            DataSource data = null;
            try {
                data = (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("jndi/mysql");
                System.out.println("Conexion Exitosa");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("NO JALO" + e.getMessage());
            }   
            return data;
        }
    }
```

`

/*************************SERVER.xml Liberty Server***************************//

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to 
    the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

<!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

<library id="JTDS">
    <fileset dir="resources/sqlserver" includes="mysql-connector-java-6.0.3"/>
</library>
```

```
<webApplication id="moii-srv-war" location="moii-srv-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" name="moii-srv-war">
<classloader commonLibraryRef="JTDS"/>
 </webApplication>
```

I expected to have the console print message Conexion Exitosa to can use this data source for another module:

Error Log : Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jndi/mysql' available: not found in JNDI environment

Comment: Are you using WebSphere Liberty as the application server? If so, where's the datasource registered in it?

Comment: Currently, I have registered in the server.xml but I try to make the next convention for java class ways. Regards   [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/rwlp_ds_appdefined.html)

Comment: It seems you are registering the datasource with one name and looking it up with another name. Maybe you should change `@Resource(lookup = "jndi/mysql")` to `@Resource(lookup = "java:comp/env/jdbc/mysql")`. Also, please include the datasource definition in the web.xml file. It should have the same name.

Comment: Also, I would argue that defining the datasource inside your application is a bad practice. The whole point is to decouple the database definition from your application, but you are entangling both.

Comment: I already change the name of the resource and add the configuration for the web.xml however I have the following message. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIException: com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: J2CA8022E: Application moii- srv-war does not have any shared libraries that provide com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver for dataSource java: comp / env / jdbc / mysql

Comment: I think the same but is for a job project requirement .... :/